# Type of pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

First of all, sorry for this stupid question. But I really need to know about the languages which are used to show execution flow of program in computer science books.

Example:

```
 1   A = 4
 2   t1 = A * B
 3   L1: t2 = t1 / C
 4   if t2 < W goto L2
 5   M = t1 * k
 6   t3 = M + I
 7   L2: H = I
 8   M = t3 - H
 9   if t3 ≥ 0 goto L3
10   goto L1
11   L3: halt
```

Does this language have some specific standers? Is this a pseudo code or an intermediate form of code?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't "pseudocode"?

Comment: It looks like high level assembly...pretty sure that is pseudocode, though. Pseudocode doesn't really have a standard. It's just that: 'fake code'. It's there purely for the purposes of making code readable for someone who doesn't understand programming. It is used to facilitate design concepts and implementation of actual code.

Comment: From my experience there is no standard *at all*. It is quite a pain to read through different books sometimes.

Comment: It is not a stupid question, and no there is not a standard for pseudocode, everybody writes it a different way.

Comment: I have seen many example. pseudo code is either in English or in some other languages syntax i.e. C, FORTRAN etc. I was not able to find conventions about this style of pseudo code.

Comment: I actually have to present some analysis work on Java bytecode. But that is difficult to understand. I was just wondering if there is some intermediate format to present it such that non familiar viewers could understand too. Then I came across this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no technical rules for Pseudocode, unless you are attempting to conform to standards/syntax for a particular language.

Pseudocode is meant to be human readable and still convey the flow and meaning of the code.

Books that use Pseudocode typically conform to a Java, C, or Pascal-type (among others) structure to make the code easy to read for those familiar with the languages.

The naming conventions that I have seen in the past usually lean toward C or Java-esque naming conventions.

You can find more information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of pseudocode is to describe an algorithm in a manner which is readable and unambiguous. (Different authors place different amount of emphasis on those two goals, which are frequently in opposition.)

Pseudocode does not need to look like english (or another spoken/written language), nor does it need to look like a real programming language. Ideally its constructs should be familiar to programmers of many different languages.

That pseudocode fills that requirement fairly well... I don't see anything in it which I can't readily understand the effect of.